# Remember current working directory when opening new tab in linux terminal Tilda

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I think my question is pretty clear when I try to open a new tab in my terminal(`tilda`) it doesn't remember the last working directory.

For example:

**Current Tab**:

ranveer@ranveer:/etc$

**After opening new Tab**:

ranveer@ranveer:~$

What I need is when I open new tab the current directory is set to last working directory `/etc` in above case.

I know I can use an application like `tmux` for the above feature but sometimes I just like to work in new tab rather than new window pane.

Comment: Well, what "terminal" are you using? You are only showing us output from your shell (most likely a bash) and bash doesn't have tabs. Gnome-Terminal as shipped with Debians has the behaviour you are looking for ...

Comment: @user1129682: oh sorry I am new to all this. I am using `tilda` drop down terminal